# What is CGAL::data_file_path()?

Tags: cmake, cgal

I am trying to use Cmake to build a program that uses CGAL.  In my CMakeLists.txt file I have this:

```
find_package(CGAL REQUIRED QUIET COMPONENTS Core)
```

Running cmake produces this message:

```
CMake Warning at /usr/local/lib/cmake/CGAL/CGALConfig.cmake:92 (message):
  CGAL_DATA_DIR cannot be deduced, set the variable CGAL_DATA_DIR to set the
  default value of CGAL::data_file_path()
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package)
```

I'm not sure what CGAL::data_file_path() is supposed to be and I can't locate it so far in the CGAL documentation.  Does anyone know something about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open the [CGAL documentation page](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/index.html) and type the text `"data_file_path"` into the search field in the upper right corner, you'll get:

> std::string CGAL::data_file_path (const std::string & filename)
> returns the full path of a data file from CGAL.

> The data files are located in the data directory of a CGAL release or in the directory Data/data from a git branch checkout. That function uses as prefix the environment variable CGAL_DATA_DIR if set, and the value of the macro CGAL_DATA_DIR otherwise. When using cmake and a standard CGAL setup, linking the target using that function with the target CGAL::Data will automatically set the macro CGAL_DATA_DIR pointing to the data directory of the CGAL version used. The function will attempt to open the file at the returned location and will print a warning message via std::cerr if the file could not be opened.

Also you can find examples of using the `data_file_path` function in the CGAL `examples` directory (which is not installed by default AFAIK).

If you don't call this function in your code, then you can ignore the CMake warning you're asking about - that's what I do for a long time. Also you can get rid of this warning, if you set the `CGAL_DATA_DIR` macro in the `CMakeLists.txt`, for example:

```
set(CGAL_DATA_DIR ".")
```

There are other ways to set this directory prefix as well - via an environment variable `CGAL_DATA_DIR`, or as an option in the CMake call etc.

Comment: Thanks!  I thought I searched the CGAL documentation but evidently I missed it.  Thanks for politely pointing it out!